# Php simple html dom extracting certain img

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

Anyone with some knodledge of the PHP simple html dom parser?
I´ve read the documentation at [Php simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

The thing im trying to do, is to find specific img urls that contains drupal-images on a page source. for example: 
    "http://drupal-        images.tv2.dk/sites/images.tv2.dk/files/t2img/2016/02/22/480x270/227713601-   42562915-273368722d35758cde85a1320a6bb23b.jpeg"

and only find images which contains the word: drupal-images. Is this possible?.

The only thing i´ve done so far, is to extract all images from a page, like this.

```
include("simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html("http://www.tv2.dk");
// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

If you should find certain images with the ....
would you use reqular expressions inside foreach?

And can I find the meta? like this:
          meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)

I´ve searched a lot and it seems that i can only find with finding specific divs and classes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `strpos()` can help you in that:

```
    $str = 'drupal-images';
    $url = 'http://drupal-images.tv2.dk/sites/images.tv2.dk/files/t2img/2016/02/22/480x270/227713601-42562915-273368722d35758cde85a1320a6bb23b.jpeg';
    $urlArray = explode('/',$url);
    if(strpos($url, $str) > 0){
        $img = end($urlArray);
    }
```

I believe you can find how to use this example in your code.

Regarfing meta data, you can use `exif_read_meta()`, more can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php